# Change password length for MariaDB

Tags: debian, mariadb, phpmyadmin, debian-buster

I'm currently working with mariadb and phpmyadmin on my debian 10 server. For some reason mariadb only allows passwords with a maximum length of 79 characters. If I specify a password that is longer than 79 characters I can easily login to phpmyadmin over the loginpage. But when I try to login to mariadb over the command prompt with the same password I get the error response: "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".
Is there a way to enable longer passwords?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mariadb client and related tools have an inbuilt [80 character](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/7c58e97bf6f80a251046c5b3e7bce826fe058bd6/mysys/get_password.c#L65) when reading tty passwords.

This doesn't apply to the password command line argument, environment variables or configuration files specification.